# Is Skype dedicated phone number avaiable for BOT?

Tags: botframework, skype, ivr

I'm looking for a information if Microsoft`s Botframework SDK supports calling to Skype bot via dedicated phone number (https://www.skype.com/en/features/online-number).

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2055 as @ghost stated, adding a phone number to a Skype calling but will perhaps be in future releases.

But the problem is that this issue/feature request is closed, and no one said anything if it is supported now. Almost 2 years passed...

Does anyone manage to create that kind of bot?

Comment: At this time, Skype doesn't support assigning phone numbers to bots. [Twilio does](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-twilio?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), however.

Comment: We're at the point where we prefer Microsoft's Voice/LUIS framework, but don't appear to have a good option to attach a phone number per application/bot. Twilio has some great functionality, but doesn't appear to "do it all" and doesn't appear to allow live streaming out meaning there will be a latency delay if we try to forward the audio to Microsoft? Anyone run into other options? One I haven't explored as a possible pipe to LUIS yet is: https://developer.nexmo.com/voice/voice-api/guides/endpoints Any others?